# ESLint simple-import-sort Groupings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, eslint

I am trying to use the `eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort` library to sort my imports. I am trying to get my imports to look like this:

```js
import firstAction from 'actions/firstAction';
import secondAction from 'actions/secondAction'

import firstActionTypes from 'actions/firstAction/types'
```

My `.eslintrc.json` file looks like this (*omitted for clarity*):

```json
"plugins": ["react", "simple-import-sort"]

...

"overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {
        "simple-import-sort/imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "groups": [
              ["^(actions)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(reducers)(/.*|$)"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

And I simply just do not know the correct Regex pattern to get the imports to sort how I need, with the appropriate whitespace. Each `[]` in the `groups` array does separate with whitespace automatically, so I really just need the Regex pattern to make the `actions/*/types` imports come after the `actions/*` imports.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a way to do it which does what I need:

```js
...

"overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {
        "simple-import-sort/imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "groups": [
              ["^(actions)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(actions)(/.*)(types)"],
              ["^(reducers)(/.*|$)"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Sorry for the premature question post, mods can delete if needed, or leave it if it helps the community.

Thanks!